# Is it necessary to initialize all the used registers in inline assembly?

Tags: gcc, assembly, inline-assembly

I am testing simple inline assembly code using gcc. And I find the result of the following code unexpected:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    unsigned x0 = 0, x1 = 1, x2 = 2;
    __asm__ volatile("movl %1, %0;\n\t"
                     "movl %2, %1"
                     :"=r"(x0), "+r"(x1)
                     :"r"(x2)
                     :);
    printf("%u, %u\n", x0, x1);
    return 0;
}
```

The printed result is `1, 1`, rather than the expected `1, 2`. Then I compiled the code with `-S` option and found out gcc generated the code as

```
movl %eax, %edx;
movl %edx, %eax;
```

`%0` and `%2` are using the same register, why?

I want gcc to generate, say,

```
movl %eax, %edx;
movl %ecx, %eax;
```

If I add `"0"(x1)` to the input constraints, gcc will generate the code above. Does it mean that all registers need to be initialized before being used in inline assembly?

Comment: You need to look at the [early clobber](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Modifiers.html) constraint.

Comment: Adding the earlyclobber modifier to the input constraint of `%0` works: `"=&r(x0)"`. Thank you! @DavidWohlferd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Moving my comment to an 'Answer' so this question can be closed.*

To prevent the compiler from re-using a register for both an input and an output, you can use the [early clobber](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Modifiers.html) constraint (for example `=&r (x)`), which informs the compiler that the register associated with the parameter is

> written before the instruction is finished using the input operands.

While this can be a good thing (since it reduces the number of registers that must made available before calling your asm), it can also cause problems (as you have seen).  So, either make sure you have finished using all the inputs before writing to the output, or use `&` to tell the compiler not to do this optimization.

For completeness, let me also point out that using inline asm is usually a [bad idea](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm).